# Create json file from makefile using git tags

Tags: git, makefile, package.json

I would like to create (replace if file exists) a json file called versions that contains the `git tags --list` version list. How do I do this with a make file?

```
VERSION := $(shell cat package.json | awk '/"version":/ {gsub(/("|",)/,"",$$2);print $$2};')

tag:
  git tag -f $(VERSION)

version-list:
  git tag --list
```

make version-list should create this file

```json
{
  "versions": [
    "0.1.0",
    "0.1.1",
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use jq for manipulating JSON:

```sh
$ git tag --list | jq -nR '{versions:[inputs]}'
{
  "versions": [
    "v2.0",
    "v2.0.1",
    "v2.1-beta",
    "v2.1.1-beta"
  ]
}
```

Explanation:

- `-n`: Don't read any input
- `-R`: Interpret input as raw text, not JSON.
- `inputs`: Get all lines. [See also](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#IO).
- `[...]`: Turn lines into list
- `{versions: ...}`: Wrap that list in an object with a key called versions.